# Waiting few minutes on page after that get content

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I want to get a html content like source code with C# program. However, I need to wait on page for like 30 seconds, after that get the site content. I tried with below code but I couldn't wait on the page. How can I solve this issue?

```
_url = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_url);
                string result = "";
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);

                using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {

                    using (Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string charSet = httpWebResponse.CharacterSet;
                        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(_encode);
                        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "").Trim();
                        //Console.WriteLine (result);
                        //Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You could try a thread.sleep, what's the use case here, why do you need to wait 30 seconds before retrieving HTML code?

Comment: I tried but this is not working. I need because the website content can be change in 30 second. (Because of javascript)

Comment: Okay I'd say that you would want the thirty second wait client (JavaScript) side, not server (c#) side

Comment: Yes you'r right.

Comment: Then maybe you need to rephrase you're question to show how your communicating with your server via JavaScript so that we can help you at the correct layer

Comment: i don't know how can i solve this issue. I think, i need a break between request and response. I searched different webrequest properties.